# how can I kill a process in a shell script

Tags: linux, bash

My bash script has:

```
ps aux | grep foo.jar | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill
```

However, I get the following when running:

```
usage: kill [ -s signal | -p ] [ -a ] pid ...
       kill -l [ signal ]
```

Any ideas, how to fix this line?

Comment: Does `ps aux | grep foo.jar | grep -v grep` return results?

Comment: Just spotted, you're missing the minus sign before aux .... ps -aux

Comment: @thonnor `ps aux` doesn't require a hyphen. Please stop blindly conjecturing.

Comment: There's no process to kill.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath Does it not give `kill: no process ID specified` when there is no process ?

Comment: @123: No, it just shows the help.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath Doesn't for me, shows the above message. Or if you supply it with an ID not associated with a running process `kill: (99999) - No such process`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, your command is correct. *If* a `foo.jar` process is running, its PID will be passed to `kill` and (should) terminate.

Since you're getting `kill`'s usage as output, it means you're actually calling `kill` with no arguments (try just running `kill` on its own, you'll see the same message). That means that there's no output in the pipeline actually reaching `xargs`, which in turn means `foo.jar` is not running.

Try running `ps aux | grep foo.jar | grep -v grep` and see if you're actually seeing results.

Answer (score 1):

As much as you may enjoy a half dozen pipes in your commands, you may want to look at the [`pkill`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pkill) command!

> DESCRIPTION
>
> The pkill command searches the process table on the running system and signals all processes that match the criteria
>        given on the command line.

i.e.

```
pkill foo.jar
```

Answer (score -4):

Untested and a guess at best (be careful)

```
kill -9 $(ps -aux | grep foo.jar | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}')
```

I re-iterate **UNTESTED** as I'm not at work and have no access to putty or Unix.

My theory is to send the kill -9 command and get the process id from a sub shell command call.

Comment: Why would `kill -9` be the solution to a usage error with `kill`? Reasonable programs should not call `kill -9`.

Comment: kill -9 isn't the solution it is how I suggest killing the process. My answer has a stab at getting the process id - which I believe is the issue here. A missing pid.

Comment: "*My theory is to send the kill -9 command*" - sure sounds like you're suggesting sending `kill -9`. Which is irrelevant to the problem and shouldn't be done.

Comment: @dimo414 perhaps I should have explained my answer a little better. YES I am suggesting sending a kill -9 which differs from the method used in the   question, thus a little note added. What I should have re-iterrated in words of 1 syllable for you, is that it looks like the PID is missing for the kill command, so I suggest a different way of obtaining the PID and passing it to kill. Like I say in big bold letters UNTESTED (3 syllables) - just an idea.

Comment: This won't make *any* difference. You're wild guessing. Not a good attitude for SO.

Comment: The answer is in the comments already; `foo.jar` isn't in the output of `ps aux`, presumably because it is not in fact running. The command in the question uses `xargs` to pass the PID to `kill`, which would work if the earlier commands output a PID at all. A command of the form `a | xargs b` is (roughly) the same as `b $(a)`, so your answer is only suggesting adding a `-9` to `kill`, which is simply wrong.